# Domain provider for all Country Code TLDs?

Tags: domain, tld

I find it very disturbing to buy some domains from one domain provider than when I have to buy a Country Code TLD that is not supported, I have to buy from another domain provider, and thus ending up having multiple domain providers for all my domains.

I have looked at Gandi and GoDaddy. They both lack some Country Code TLDs the other one has.

Is there domain providers that has all (or almost all) Country Code TLDs?

If not, how do you guys do to get all (or almost all) domains under in one place?

Also, it would be good if someone could suggest some of the big players of domain providing besides Gandi and GoDaddy, cause I'm new to the international domain market (have only used a couple in Sweden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no really truly one-size-fits-all providers who have every single country code. Many ccTLDs still require you to email some person at some university to get a domain.

I personally use resell.biz, since they have a nice selection of ccTLDs and have REALLY excellent prices on the ones I care about. I manage around 1k domains with their system for our customers.

Moniker.com is another well respected registrar, though they are more expensive.

Other big providers include enom and tucows.

Definitely get away from Godaddy if you can. They have a reputation for playing games with customers, confiscating desirable domains, and generally making life difficult.

Comment: But if I buy country code domains from multiple domain providers, could I transfer the others to one of mine and then only use that one (even though it doesn't have support for that country code TLD - for example .dk)? Or do I have to login to multiple domain providers to manage them?

Comment: No, absolutely not. A provider can only manage a subset of all the ccTLDs. Generally this is the same list as the ones they sell directly. Each provider must negotiate an agreement with EACH ccTLD root registrar to sell and manage those domains. There is no universal system for this.

Comment: It seems that http://www.nameisp.com/default.asp manages all ccTLDs. How is this?

Comment: They have many domains, but they definitely don't have all of them. And their prices are ridiculous - $25USD per .com!

Comment: Isn't resell.biz for domain resellers only and thus not for private individuals?

Comment: resell.biz works well for reselling, but also works perfectly fine for registering domains for yourself. I manage several hundred domains that are owned directly by my company.

Comment: @Paul McMillan: How do I search and buy domains in resell.biz?

Comment: Create a user for yourself, and log yourself in as that user. Each domain needs to be associated with an account which represents a real person or corporate entity.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little old but I'm going to answer it anyway as the other posts didn't really answer the main question.

I had the same problem but eventually came across 101domains.com

They have all country domain names as far as I can tell, which is quite convenient.

On the other hand, unless you are google, I don't think you can register your website with all country domains. It's not only quite expensive but also most countries require you to be a resident, citizen, or have a business in that country, or at least a local address. I wanted to do the same for my domain but gave up on the idea because of the cost and requirements. Wish you good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother personally, there are hundreds of country TLDs, registering and managing all these domains would be expensive, time consuming and just plain unnecessary. Nobody else does this, I'd suggest getting the 'big' domains but having them all throw you back to a originating-domain-hinted multi-country menu with a cookie.

Comment: But how do big players do like facebook? They buy everything on multiple domain providers basically, no magic at all? =)

Comment: But they don't buy everything (Facebook.zr anybody?), and they could if they wanted, they'd have a dept just to do it, but they don't.

Comment: Yes, though the really big players like Google are registrars in their own right, and purchase directly from the root.